# UIViewController to UIImagePickerController to other UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an iOS app where the user should be able to create objects that have multiple photos.

Right now I have two ViewControllers: A and B.
View controller A displays a list of all created objects and a button to switch to view controller B.
View controller B is responsible for creating new objects. It consists of a CollectionView that displays all photos already taken for that object and a button that launches a UIImagePickerController to take a new Photo.

Use Case:

1. In ViewController A the user clicks the button to create a new object
2. ViewController B loads with no photos in the collection view.
3. User has to click the button in ViewController B to load the UIImagePickerController.
4. User takes a photo, returns to ViewController B
5. User can take another photo.

I want to combine step 2 and 3. I.e.

1. User clicks button in ViewController A
2. UIImagePickerController gets loaded
3. User takes a photo, returns to ViewController B

At the moment I start the UIImagePickerController in the viewDidAppear of ViewController B, but then first the ViewController B appears, and the the UIImagePickerController.

Edit: I am using a storyboard to do all this.
ViewController A is in a Navigation Controller, ViewController B is in an other Navigation Controller, and i am using a modal storyboard segue for the transition.

Comment: But you are not revealing your view controller architecture / hierarchy, which is what the question is all about. Please specify HOW you are "loading" the view controllers. For example, I presume the UIImagePickerController is a _presented_ view controller, yes? What about View Controller B?

Comment: you could count the number of collections and then decide where to send the user to, if he clicks the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are presenting the image picker as a modal view, my thought would be to write a method on your View Controller B that presents an image picker controller on an arbitrary view controller. For instance: `-(void)presentImagePickerFromViewController:(UIViewController *)vc completion:(void (^)(void))completion`. In your View Controller A, instantiate a View Controller B object, and call this method on it passing `self` for the view controller. In the completion block, now present the View Controller B on the navigation stack without animation. This way, your View Controller B gets the information direct from the image picker, encapsulates all the image code in View Controller B, and lets you go direct to View Controller B once finished with the picker.

If, on the other hand, you are presenting the image picker on the navigation stack, you could probably call the `setViewControllers:animated:` method on the navigation controller from one of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` callbacks. I haven't tested this myself, but I believe this method allows you to insert view controllers into the navigation stack.

Hope this helps!